# Managing files into modules/ Sails.js

Tags: rest, module, sails.js

Can I separate my files into different modules? For example, I want to have such structure:

api/Module1/... (Controllers, Services, Models folders)

api/Module2/... (Controllers, Services, Models folders)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately for you, no; not without breaking how Sails implements MVC.

What you *can* do for **controllers** is organize it like this:

```
/api/controllers/model1/MyController.js
/api/controllers/model2/YourController.js
/api/controllers/model3/TheirController.js
```

Do note that if organized in this manner, as per the [sails controllers documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/controllers),

> that the subfolder name will become part of the Controller’s identity when used for routing

Comment: Are there any other ways to organize my project files?

Comment: Not without modifying how sails configures itself. You *can* arrange your views however you want,  assuming you're not relying on default blueprints.

Comment: What files shoud I modify?